# Insert line into multi specified files

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to insert a line into the start of multiple specified type files, which the files are located in current directory or the sub dir.

I know that using

```
find . -name "*.csv"
```

can help me to list the files I want to use for inserting.

and using

```
sed -i '1icolumn1,column2,column3' test.csv
```

can use to insert one line at the start of file,

but now I do NOT know how to pipe the filenames from "find" command to "sed" command.

Could anybody give me any suggestion?

Or is there any better solution to do this?

BTW, is it work to do this in one line command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `xargs` to pass output of `find` and command line arguments to next command, here `sed`

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '1icolumn1,column2,column3'
```

---

Another option would be to use `-exec` option of `find`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sed -i '1icolumn1,column2,column3' {} \;
```

---

**Note :** It has been observed that `xargs` is more efficient way and can handle multiple processes using `-P` option.

Answer (score 2):

This way :

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i '1icolumn1,column2,column3' {} +
```

`-exec` do all the magic here. The relevant part of `man find` :

```
   -exec command ;
   Execute  command;  true  if  0  status  is returned.  All following arguments
   to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting
   of `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name
   being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just
   in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions  of find.   Both  of  
   these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect
   them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of
   the use of the -exec option.  The specified command is run once for each
   matched file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.   There
   are unavoidable security  problems  surrounding use of the -exec action;
   you should use the -execdir option instead
```

Comment: Thanks, this work very well! And thank you very much for your explaination on exec.